# Can I assign multiple variables the same value without having one line per variable/assignment?

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a less verbose way to instantiate multiple variables to the same value. I currently have this:

```
let a = 0;
let b = 0;
let c = 0;
let d = 0;
let e = 0;
let f = 0;
let g = 0;
let h = 0;
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
let k = 0;
let l = 0;
let m = 0;
let n = 0;
let o = 0;
```

And I am looking to do something like this:

```
let { a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o } = 0;
```

All these variables return `undefined`. There **surely** has to be a better way to instantiate multiple variables to the same value? I am using `let` as these values change over time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) your variables as an array as follows, though you need to know the number of elements, and it does require ES6+:

```js
let [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o] = Array(15).fill(0);
```

Comment: That's neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I would do.

```js
const [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o] = repeat(0);

console.log(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o);

function* repeat(x) {
    while (true) yield x;
}
```

Related question: [How to use destructuring assignment to define enumerations in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39673627/783743)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a generator which yields the wanted value for a destructuring with an array.

```js
function* always(v) {
    while(true) yield v;
}

let [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o] = always(0);

console.log(a);
console.log(o);
```